# Is there a way to customise the web editor?

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm not sure whether the one in the video is official, but I'm making a Roblox executor in the Lua language for Monaco, and I was wondering if there is a way to customise Monaco (e.g. changing some text colours for language stuff and links/strings)? The tutorial I followed was this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2foHIdCKBec&t=602s

Also, is there a way to make a preview on the right of what's in the editor?

Comment: In the future, please don't capitalize each word, only capitalise the first letter of a sentence, the word "I" (first person singular), and names (e.g. of persons, products and countries. Use lowercase for normal words.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in an Q&A style. But for a start investigate concepts like Monaco syntax highlighting, tokenization, themes.